# JSON Unicode httpequest

Tags: android, json, http, unicode, request

I wanna make Unicode httprequest, althogh I changed my String to Unicode but there is some "?????" instead of My app name in my SQL database. ( my App name is in farsi)

```
 List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dev_name", G.give_device_model()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dev_ID", G.give_device_ID()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("follow_code", inputActivation.getText().toString()));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("app_name",convert_2_unicode(msg) ));


            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(ur_register_app, "POST", params);
```

and this is my function for convert to Unicode:

```
  public String convert_2_unicode(String str){

        String string = "";
        try {
            // Convert from Unicode to UTF-8

            byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF-8");

            // Convert from UTF-8 to Unicode
            string = new String(utf8, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        }

        return string;
    }
```

how can send proper Unicode Request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's finnaly solved,
in JSON parser I used:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(paramsHTTP.UTF_8));
```

instead of:

```
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params ));
```

Answer (score 0):

May be there is incorrect collation set on your database or table.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html

You can check this with phpMyAdmin.

Comment: my db collation is Ok, cause when I pass parameters from URL they saved right in unicode.

Comment: My guess it depends on way you make request.